# Simplification of Karnaugh Table

Tags: boolean-algebra

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
abc/de& 000 & 001 & 011 & 010 & 110 & 111 & 101 & 100 \\ \hline
 00& 1 & 0 & 0 & - & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\\ \hline
 01& 0 & - &  1 & 0 & 0 & - & - & 0\\ \hline
 11& 0 & - & 1 & 0 & 0 & - & - & 0 \\ \hline10
& 1 & - & 0 & - & - & 0 &1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
where "-" means dont care

Then i have found three islands:

1. (~E~C)
2. (A~B~E)
3. (EC)

Are thoes all implicants couse i've been wondering if i should add (~B~ED)

Is this the simplest form or can i do something to mininilinze it?